# Eliminar signos de una cadena en SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

Tengo una duda con respecto a una cadena de alfanuméricos, tengo que validar que dicha cadena si trae un alfanumérico, por ejemplo:

```
EJEMPLO123+
```

Eliminar el sigo `"+"` y quedarme con el alfanumérico solamente.

Comment: Revisa la función [`REPLACE`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/replace-transact-sql)

Comment: Si la cadena es `123+`, entonces no habría que hacer el reemplazo?, El `+` siempre aparece al final de la cadena?

Comment: @PatricioMoracho creo que se refiere a quitar ese signo, si la cadena es `123+`, al final debería quedar `123`.

Comment: Así es, solo quiero que quede el 123 en vez del 123+

Comment: Si se trata solamente de quitar el signo `+` de la cadena, puedes hacerlo con `REPLACE`, como ya te indicó @Flxtr. Te quitará ese signo donde quiera que esté y las veces que esté en esa cadena.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Podrías crearte una función que elimine los caracteres que no te interesan.

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.EliminaNoAlfanumericos(@variable varchar(100)) RETURNS VARCHAR(100)
BEGIN
    DECLARE @posicion INT
    SET @posicion = PATINDEX('%[^A-Za-z0-9]%',@variable )
    WHILE @posicion > 0
       BEGIN
          SET @variable = STUFF(@variable ,@posicion ,1,'')
          SET @posicion = PATINDEX('%[^A-Za-z0-9]%',@variable )
       END
    RETURN @variable
END
GO
```

La función lo que hace es un bucle buscando, con `PATINDEX`, los caracteres no alfanuméricos que contiene la `@variable` hasta que no quede ninguno, y mediante la función `STUFF`, va sustituyendo por blanco `''` el carácter que encuentra en la `@posición` dentro de la `@variable`.